# VMware Fusion multiple users at same time

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have a client who wants to make it possible for multiple users to log into his  virtual windows machine on his mac simultaneously, but whenever another user logs in, it boots off the current user.

So to clarify, on his mac he has vmware installed so that he can have Quickbooks et al installed and other windows apps.

However, he has users in various locations that need to access that particular instance of Windows ON his mac.  So, they use VMWare fusion to log directly into this instance remotely, but apparently he needs different people to log into the instance at the same time and when one tries to login while another user is on, they get bumped off.

Is this even possible and if so, is there a particular way to do it?

Comment: The same thing happens when connecting remotely to workstation versions of Windows running on real physical hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the way you're trying to do it now. How can many people control the same mouse cursor? It would not work.

The only way this would work, is if everyone uses Remote Desktop to log into their own desktop environment. For this to work, you actually do need a Terminal Server edition of Remote Desktop, which comes with a Server version of windows, or additional third party software.

I am aware of a hack for remote desktop for desktop versions of windows which can allow multiple users to RDP into the same machine without logging others out, but its not the preferred way, especially not in a business environment.

Comment: Just to clarify, Do you mean Apple/MAC's Remote Desktop program?

Comment: Remote desktop is a protocol which is natively supported by Windows. Mac has their own client and Microsoft has made RD Client for mac as well. So yes, Apple/MAC's Remote Desktop program can be used, but its the server portion I'm talking about.

Comment: I ask partly because I'm not 100% sure how they connect with VMware fusion.  When they connect to the windows virtual machine on the mac are they connecting directly with that instance or are they logging in as a user on the mac and then utilizing the instance?  I've used virtual machines and logged in remotely but have never done anything like he is attempting.  What do you think?

Comment: I don't know how they do it now, but the only way for this to work properly (and I bet this is how they attempt to do it) is by connecting to the RDP protocol directly on the windows. So the VMWare guest is placed in the normal network and is accessible directly. But as stated, if you don't run a terminal server environment, by default when a new user connects, the old one (and the host included) is disconnected.